# When working with SQL databases, what are the primary benefits of using an Update statement in the backend instead of using a Prepared function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to work with a specific database and I'm not sure why one would use an update statement rather than a prepare statement.

What is the primary difference between the two?

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE credential SET nickname= ?,email= ?,address= ?,Password= ?,PhoneNumber= ? where ID=$id;");
$sql->bind_param("sssss",$input_nickname,$input_email,$input_address,$hashed_pwd,$input_phonenumber); 
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
```

```
$sql = "UPDATE credential SET nickname='$input_nickname',email='$input_email',address='$input_address',Password='$hashed_pwd',PhoneNumber='$input_phonenumber' where ID=$id;";
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` and running a prepared statement are not mutually exclusive. Most SQL statements can be 'prepared'.

So this is not an either/or question. If you need to do an UPDATE statement, you should probably always used prepared statements.

Your second example that doesn't use prepared statement will *very likely* have a SQL injection-related security bug. Avoiding these security bugs is the biggest reason to use prepared statements.